# MongoDB - Bulk find and updateOne not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Can you guys spot as to why the following Bulk query is not working. I am not getting any errors, it's just simply not executing the changes on the database. When I execute the same queries using mongoose's findOneAndUpdate method it works just fine.

Please see code below:

```
var bulk = models.Cart.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp()

        bulk.find({
            $and: [
                { $or: [{ userId }, { sessionId }] },
                { 'cartProducts.productId': { $ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(args.data.productId) } },
                { checkedOut: false }
            ]
        }).updateOne({
            $push: {
                cartProducts: { productId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(args.data.productId), quantity: args.data.quantity }
            }
        })

        bulk.find({
            $and: [
                { $or: [{ userId }, { sessionId }] },
                { 'cartProducts.productId': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(args.data.productId) },
                { checkedOut: false }
            ]
        }).updateOne({
            $set: {
                'cartProducts.$.quantity': args.data.quantity
            }
        })

bulk.execute()
```

Again, executing those same queries when executing `findOneAndUpdate` works just fine

```
models.Cart.findOneAndUpdate({
        $and: [
                { $or: [{ userId }, { sessionId }] },
                { 'cartProducts.productId': { $ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(args.data.productId) } },
                { checkedOut: false }
            ]
        }, {
            $push: {
                cartProducts: { productId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(args.data.productId), quantity: args.data.quantity }
            }
        }, 
{ new: true })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was at `userId` I was passing a `string` but it required an `ObjectId`